# Is using @Nonnull (javax) on entities with Hibernate a bad idea?

Tags: java, hibernate, null-safety

We are using Hibernate in our Spring Boot application. Whenever we can, we use `@javax.annotation.Nonnull` and `@javax.annotation.Nullable` annotations to help us and the IDE identify, whether we can expect `null` values from fields/methods/parameters/etc.

For consistency, I would also like to use `@Nonnull` in `@Entity` classes whenever I have a table column declared `not null`. However, some of my colleagues argue that you should not do this as it cannot be guaranteed on entities due to the way Hibernate instantiates objects.
One suggestion was to use `@Nonnull` only on accessors and `return requireNonNull(value)` on getters.

What is your opinion on the matter? Or maybe it is not an opinion, and they are just right. What is the right way to be null-safe when accessing entity properties?

PS: I could not find anything on the topic that does not deal with validation, which is not the intention here.